# Java "Reference" workaround for ZeroMQ for sending objects over a ZMQ socket

Tags: java, reference, zeromq

I have a Java program which uses ZeroMQ sockets for inter-process communication. I have thread workers that do some expensive work and as they finish their work with a result I want to pass that result object to a "sender" thread over an inproc socket, so that it can send the object to a client. I have seen examples, in C++ this is usually done using pointers, but in Java there are no pointers and I do not want to serialize the object just to be able to pass the object to another thread.

What are the possibilities that I have? I can only pass "lightweight" values to the socket, like strings or primitive types efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you pass a reference or a pointer it is much the same.  You can pass it between threads in the same process via a data structure, but you cannot pass it via a socket and expect it to work in a different process.

i.e. to pass a reference (or a pointer) between threads in the same process don't use ZeroMQ, use something like a BlockingQueue instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but I do serialize the objects because clients and servers are written in different languages on different platforms. It also allows me to debug messages using a simple proxy that prints them.

I use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize/deserialize objects either as JSON or XML strings, and it's quite easy to use.

Another solution is [GSon](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/), but I found that it serializes dates in the JVM's time zone and I need to send/receive messages to/from computers running on different time zones. XStream uses GMT as the default time zone.

Comment: I use msgpack (jumped off from protocol buffers) for object serialization across platforms, it is very fast!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt. It is not about sendig references to another process over zeromq. That would never work. The question is for inproc worker threads, sending messages means serilizing and deserilizing. For strings and primitive types, it is trivial, but for large business objects it does not make sense (unless i am missing a trick).

The other workaround is to have the business objects (or in your case the result) stored in a cache by your worker thread, and just pass the index to the "sender" thread. This "sender" thread will get the result from the cache and send it to the "client".

However i am not sure if this is the intended purpose. I have put up the same query in this same forum.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing now. Thanks.